# Is there any way to sail the Danube on a budget?

Tags: budget, europe, sailing, rivers, danube

I'd like to sail down the Danube next summer, on my own, on as small and cheap a vessel as possible (no big motor boat, maybe not even a motor boat at all). I haven't decided on the length of the trip, but would expect a couple of hundred kilometers during a couple of weeks.

Using a raft with no guidance is probably a pipe dream, as I have zero sailing experience and no equipment. (I asked a question over on  [outdoors.stackexchange.com](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/questions/5/can-i-sail-a-raft-on-a-european-river-with-commercial-traffic) some time ago.)

Are there any services along the Danube that offer long-term rentals, some amount of training/introduction to navigation basics, equipment like lifejackets, etc., and with whom one could return the boat further downstream?

While seeing the Danube delta would be great, I'm totally open in regards to where to start or end the journey.

Comment: Can you give us a rough idea of your budget - what do you consider cheap?

Comment: Some French guys went on a raft from Budapest to the Black Sea, 12 years ago. It's possible, but not necessarily "cheap". The website is in French, but there are some pictures and videos: http://www.atypiq.com/danube/

Comment: At present it's a really vague question and hard to answer directly.  I mean, someone could answer 'buy a kayak and start paddling' - and that'd be valid, no? (A friend did that from Vancouver to Alaska, no experience).  For this reason I'm voting to close, but editing it may help

Comment: @Mark I'm looking for a (professional, commercial) service that offers basic guidance + rentals somewhere along the stream. Any ideas on how to edit the question to make that clearer?

Comment: This question was closed 4 years ago and lots  users since then have become senior members and hence may have really good answers now. I think we can reopen this question and get some valuable knowledge in the site's archives! Reopen voted.